# Deriving Full JPath with Array Index

Tags: javascript, java, json

Trying to derive Full JPATH if Object is an Array.

Running below code,

```
var INPUT = ['ADDR.ADDR_L1','NAME.FIRST_NAME','CONTACT.TYPE','LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2OBJ','LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2ARR.LEVEL3OBJ'];

var obj = {
                  "ID":"1",
                  "NAME":{"FIRST_NAME":"ABC","LAST_NAME":"XYZ"},
                  "ADDR":
                        [{"TYPE":"HOME",
                          "ADDR_L1":"SDGSG",
                          "CITY":"AFAFA"},
                         {"TYPE":"OFFC",
                          "ADDR_L1":"AFASF",
                          "CITY":"SDGSDG"}],
                  "CONTACT":
                        [{"TYPE":"A"},{"TYPE":"B"},{"TYPE":"C"}],
                  "LEVEL1OBJ":{"LEVEL2ARR":[
                                            {"LEVEL3OBJ":"A"},
                                            {"LEVEL3OBJ":"B"}],
                                "LEVEL2OBJ":"GFDB"
                  }
                  };

var jpath1=[];
var jpath_final=[];
for ( var i=0;i<INPUT.length;i++)
  { // Loop over the list of JPATH coming in as INPUT
    jpath1=[];
    console.log("I"+i);
    var jpath = INPUT[i].split('.'); //Splitting keys in an array
    console.log(jpath);
      for ( var j=0;j<jpath.length;j++)
        { //loop over all keys in input
          console.log("J"+j);
          var subjpath=jpath[j];
          console.log(jpath.length);
          console.log(subjpath);
              for ( var key of Object.keys(obj) ) //getting all keys on obj
                {  
                  console.log("KEY");
                  console.log(key);
  
                  if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === '[object Array]' && subjpath == key ) //if object is an array
                    {
                        console.log("yes");
                        console.log(obj[key].length);
                        for ( var k=0;k<obj[key].length;k++)
                            { //looping over all array index
                                console.log("k"+k);
                                jpath1.push(subjpath+'.'+k); //appending array index to original jpath
                                console.log(jpath1);
                            }
                    }
                  else if ( key == subjpath )
                   {
                     jpath1.push(subjpath);
                     subjpath="";
                   }
                }
          
          }
//appending other objects after array object
          jpath1.forEach((element, index) => {
  jpath1[index] = element + '.' + subjpath;
    });
console.log(jpath1);      
          jpath_final.push(jpath1);
          
          console.log(jpath_final);
}
```

Current Output:

```
[
  [ 'ADDR.0.ADDR_L1', 'ADDR.1.ADDR_L1' ],
  [ 'NAME.FIRST_NAME' ],
  [ 'CONTACT.0.TYPE', 'CONTACT.1.TYPE', 'CONTACT.2.TYPE' ],
  [ 'LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2OBJ' ],
  [ 'LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL3OBJ' ] --Incorrect
]
```

The process is working for scenario where Array Object is first level. But not working for 2nd Level onwards array object. I know i need to perform it recursively but corrupting the result if I take out Object.keys loop as function.

Expected Output

```
[
  [ 'ADDR.0.ADDR_L1', 'ADDR.1.ADDR_L1' ],
  [ 'NAME.FIRST_NAME' ],
  [ 'CONTACT.0.TYPE', 'CONTACT.1.TYPE', 'CONTACT.2.TYPE' ],
  [ 'LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2OBJ' ],
  [ 'LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2ARR.0.LEVEL3OBJ' ,'LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2ARR.1.LEVEL3OBJ' ]
]
```

Meanwhile I tried something more which gives close to what i needed,

```
var INPUT = ['ADDR.ADDR_L1','NAME.FIRST_NAME','CONTACT.TYPE','LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2OBJ','LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2ARR.LEVEL3OBJ'];

var obj = {
                  "ID":"1",
                  "NAME":{"FIRST_NAME":"ABC","LAST_NAME":"XYZ"},
                  "ADDR":
                        [{"TYPE":"HOME",
                          "ADDR_L1":"SDGSG",
                          "CITY":"AFAFA"},
                         {"TYPE":"OFFC",
                          "ADDR_L1":"AFASF",
                          "CITY":"SDGSDG"}],
                  "CONTACT":
                        [{"TYPE":"A"},{"TYPE":"B"},{"TYPE":"C"}],
                  "LEVEL1OBJ":{"LEVEL2ARR":[
                                            {"LEVEL3OBJ":"A"},
                                            {"LEVEL3OBJ":"B"}],
                                "LEVEL2OBJ":"GFDB"
                  }
                  };
var jpath_final=[];

function append_index(jp,index)
{
  if ( jpath_final[i] == null )
  {
  jpath_final[i] = jp+'.'+index; 
  }
  else
  {
    jpath_final[i] += '.'+jp+'.'+index;
  }
  return;

}

function append_jpath(jp)
{
  if ( jpath_final[i] == null )
  {
  jpath_final[i] = jp; 
  }
  else
  {
    jpath_final[i] += '.'+jp;
  }
  return;
}


function chk_func ( obj,jpath )
{

     for ( var key of Object.keys(obj)  )
        {
          console.log("Print Key:"+key);    
          console.log("JPATH "+jpath);
          console.log("J " + j);
          if ( j == jpath.length-1 )
          {
             console.log("Enter 1st if");
             append_jpath(jpath[j]);
             j++;
             console.log("JPATH "+ jpath_final[i]);
             return;
          }
          else
          {
            if ( typeof obj[key] == 'object' && key == jpath[j] && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) != "[object Array]")
                {
                  console.log("Enter 2nd if");
                    console.log( jpath[j] + " is Object");
                    append_jpath(jpath[j]);
                    console.log( "JPATH "+jpath_final[i]);
                    j++;
                    console.log("Now Object "+ key+" "+jpath[j] );
                    chk_func(obj[key],jpath);
                    break;
                }
             else if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === "[object Array]" && key == jpath[j] )
                {
                  console.log("Enter 3rd if");
                  console.log("jpath "+jpath);
                  console.log("key "+key);
                    console.log(jpath[j] + " is Array");
                    append_index(jpath[j],obj[key].length);
                    console.log("JPATH "+jpath_final[i]);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                  continue;
                }
    
        }
        }
        
        return;
}

for ( var i=0;i<INPUT.length;i++)
  {
    console.log("i:"+i);
    var jpath = INPUT[i].split('.');
    console.log(jpath);
      for ( var j=0;j<jpath.length;j++)
        {
          console.log("j:"+j);      
          console.log(jpath[j]);
          
          if ( j < jpath.length-1 && jpath[j] != undefined )
          {
            chk_func(obj,jpath);    
          }
          else
          {
            append_jpath(jpath[j]);
            console.log("JPATH "+ jpath_final[i]);
          }
        }
  }

console.log("final "+jpath_final);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the entry point of your recursion is likely where you are stumbling.  If you'll move all of your processing into the recursive block, then you can process from a top-down approach in your object.  This also allows you to peel off layers of the object for processing as you navigate through the split path (INPUT array).

There are a few other changes in the following to be a little more efficient, and I changed a few variable names to help me keep things straight as I was debugging.

```
var INPUT = [ "ADDR.ADDR_L1", "NAME.FIRST_NAME", "CONTACT.TYPE", "LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2OBJ", "LEVEL1OBJ.LEVEL2ARR.LEVEL3OBJ"];
var main_obj = {
  ID: "1",
  NAME: { FIRST_NAME: "ABC", LAST_NAME: "XYZ" },
  ADDR: [
    { TYPE: "HOME", ADDR_L1: "SDGSG", CITY: "AFAFA" },
    { TYPE: "OFFC", ADDR_L1: "AFASF", CITY: "SDGSDG" }
  ],
  CONTACT: [{ TYPE: "A" }, { TYPE: "B" }, { TYPE: "C" }],
  LEVEL1OBJ: {
    LEVEL2ARR: [{ LEVEL3OBJ: "A" }, { LEVEL3OBJ: "B" }],
    LEVEL2OBJ: "GFDB"
  }
};

var json_final = [];
for (var keyInput of INPUT) {
  processKeys(keyInput, main_obj, keyInput);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(json_final));

function processKeys (keyInp, obj, rootKeyInp) {
  if (keyInp.includes('.')) {
    var tokens = keyInp.split('.');
    if (1 < tokens.length) {
      console.log(tokens[0] + ' :: ' + rootKeyInp);
      var keyInp0 = tokens.shift();
      if (obj[keyInp0] != null) {
        processKeys(tokens.join('.'), obj[keyInp0], rootKeyInp);
      }
    }
  } else {
    var json_arr_tmp = [];
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]") {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        let rootKeyInpSuffix = rootKeyInp.slice(-(keyInp.length + 1));
        json_arr_tmp.push(rootKeyInp.substr(0, rootKeyInp.lastIndexOf(rootKeyInpSuffix)) + '.' + i + rootKeyInpSuffix);
      }
    } else {
      json_arr_tmp.push(rootKeyInp);
    }
    json_final.push(json_arr_tmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Travis. I also tried using funcs and recursion ( added the code to the original question ). It led me to distinct list of JPATH but only the max(index) JPATH for the arrays. I was thinking to use the output and further manipulate the array using max(index). But this code gives what i exactly needed. Let me test more.